# LaTeX letter with addresses fields are in the right place - one under another

Tags: positioning, koma-script, letters, addresses

Perhaps, this question is stupid for some users, who has more experience, but I can't find any correct option (though I re-read KOMA-Script guide section about pseudo-lengths) therefore, please, accept my apologies.

I use the class scrlttr2 for letter writing, and I want to change standard placement of addressee and sender for the following reasons: the rules of business correspondence in Russia and Ukraine prescribe the following arrangement of addresses —

```
                                                        ToName
                                                        ToAddress

                                                        FromName
                                                        FromAddress

                           Dear Sir or Madam!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

According to [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/latex-letter-with-address-field-in-the-right-place-for-a-c5-envelope-with-windo)
I changed the variables `toaddrvpos` and `toaddrhpos`. And that has allowed to receive this (output of LaTeX source shown below)

[image]

The source:

```
\documentclass[backaddress=off]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10mm}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{130mm}
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}
\let\@texttop\relax
\makeatother

\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Додатки}

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Somestreet St., \\
Sometown, 12345}

\setkomavar{date}{\today}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Addressee \\
Road \\
Town}

\opening{Dear Recipient,}

\lipsum[1]

\closing{Best Regards,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

However, i'm stuck here and can't continue.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with pseudo length. A picture of all length are shown here: [How to remove space between back address and address in scrlttr2?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109797/how-to-remove-space-between-back-address-and-address-in-scrlttr2/109855#109855)

With the example below you will get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[backaddress=off,fromalign=left,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10mm}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{140mm}
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{30mm}
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{140mm}
\makeatother

\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Додатки}

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Somestreet St., \\
Sometown, 12345}

\setkomavar{date}{\today}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Addressee \\
Road \\
Town}

\opening{Dear Recipient,}

\lipsum[1]

\closing{Best Regards,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```