# How to I move the from (sender) address position to the left in a letter document class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letters

This one deals more with vertical, not horizontal, space:
[Positioning the address in a Letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172600/positioning-the-address-in-a-letter)

I know about the `scrlttr2` document class, but the `letter` class has much better default formatting (I only need to change ONE parameter), whereas the `scrlttr2` produces an aesthetically unpleasing document, which redundant output in the sender's info, and needs a lot of work to make it look like the `letter` class, which I find almost perfect:
[LaTeX letter with address field in the right place for a "C5 envelope with window"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/latex-letter-with-address-field-in-the-right-place-for-a-c5-envelope-with-windo)

I would be willing to use the `scrlttr2` class, but I can't find a template for it that makes it look like the better looking `letter` class. Here is one:

[scrlttr2: Position of the recipient's address](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164728/scrlttr2-position-of-the-recipients-address)

But I would rather just make this small fix to the `letter` class, if possible.

Here is what I have so far for my .tex file:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=2.0cm, right=3.0cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm, bindingoffset=0cm, showframe=false]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{15cm}
\newcommand{\subject}[1]{% This macro will need one argument
  {\begin{center} \bfseries \underline{#1} \end{center}}% Centred and bold text
}
\signature{Shafique Jamal}
\address{Shafique Jamal \\ 31 Streetname Drive \\ Town, Province \\ Canada ZIP POS}
\longindentation=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{\TeX Stack Exchange Group \\ Office \\ 23 Streets Name \\ Town, Country POSTAL }
\opening{Dear Fellow Stack People:}
\subject{Subject: Subject goes here}

Can you help me move the sender's address to the left? It is too close to the right edge. I would like to make sure that it does not go more to the right than does the text in the body of the letter.

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

And here is what this produces:

[image: Screenshot of LaTeX output]

The sender's address is too far to the right - I would like to bring it more to the left, so that the text of the sender's address goes no further to the right than does the text in the body of the letter. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the purpose of the line

```
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{15cm}
```

used in your code. This is the source of the problem. Commenting this will cure the disease.

On the other hand, if you are tied to a `\tabcolsep` of `15cm` (which looks weird), Add this to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\ignorespaces  %% earlier it was \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
  \fi
  \vspace{2\parskip}% 
  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\makeatother
```

Or with `etoolbox`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\opening}{\begin{tabular}{l@{}}}    %% search
                    {\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}} %% replace
                    {}{}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=2.0cm, right=3.0cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm, bindingoffset=0cm, showframe]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{15cm}
\newcommand{\subject}[1]{% This macro will need one argument
  {\begin{center} \bfseries \underline{#1} \end{center}}% Centred and bold text
}
\signature{Shafique Jamal}
\address{Shafique Jamal \\ 31 Streetname Drive \\ Town, Province \\ Canada ZIP POS}
\longindentation=0pt

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\opening}{\begin{tabular}{l@{}}}    %% search
                    {\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}} %% replace
                    {}{}


%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
%  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
%    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
%  \else  % home address
%    \thispagestyle{empty}%
%    {\hspace*{\fill}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\ignorespaces
%      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
%      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
%  \fi
%  \vspace{2\parskip}% 
%  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
%  \vspace{2\parskip}%
%  #1\par\nobreak}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{\TeX Stack Exchange Group \\ Office \\ 23 Streets Name \\ Town, Country POSTAL }
\opening{Dear Fellow Stack People:}
\subject{Subject: Subject goes here}

Can you help me move the sender's address to the left? It is too close to the right edge. I would like to make sure that it does not go more to the right than does the text in the body of the letter.

\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Harish, thanks for this answer. Yes, the line `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{15cm}` was vestigial, from something else I was trying to do. My stupid mistake, thank you for catching it and proposing this solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've always felt that the `letter` class was very restrictive and difficult in terms of its composition. It is really simple to recreate the layout in a very flexible way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.0cm, right=3.0cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm, bindingoffset=0cm, showframe=false]{geometry}
\newcommand{\subject}[1]{% This macro will need one argument
  {\begin{center} \bfseries \underline{#1} \end{center}}% Centred and bold text
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{3cm}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  Shafique Jamal \\
  31 Streetname Drive \\
  Town, Province \\
  Canada ZIP POS \\ \\
  \today
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  \TeX Stack Exchange Group \\
  Office \\
  23 Streets Name \\
  Town, Country POSTAL
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Fellow Stack People:

\subject{Subject: Subject goes here}

Can you help me move the sender's address to the left? 
It is too close to the right edge. I would like to make 
sure that it does not go more to the right than does the 
text in the body of the letter.

\bigskip

Sincerely,

\vspace{4\baselineskip}

Shafique Jamal

\end{document}
```

Comment: Werner - thanks for this. Your solution here has a large advantage over the `scrlttr2` and `letter` document classes: the `article` class allows using tables and captions, which `scrlttr2` and `letter` do not support by default. This is useful for including in a letter formatted information that is easy for the reader to quickly find. Cheers